# If it possible somehow to load data from MS SQL Server to Tabulator table?

Tags: tabulator

Is there a way to get some data from MS SQL Server to Tabulator, change data in Tabulator and then save changed data back to MS SQL Server?
I would appreciate any your suggestions. Thank you!

I am just reading documentation and getting puzzled. I do not see any hint on this.

Comment: I think there is a way of getting that done. A suggestion might be to start reading here: https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/quickstart .  SO is not about puzzles, but about questions, so, please, use [edit] and share the stuff you created, and add the question that puzzles you.

Comment: Because the question is also about getting data from MS SQL Server, you might want to add the tag: [tag:sql-server] to your question. (That would get you more readers of your question, than just tis one tag about some JavaScript library.